# Idiomatic Replacement for map/reduce/filter/etc

Tags: go

I have a list of things in a go program.  I want to loop over them, and perform some operation on/with a subset of those things.  Is there more elegant/idiomatic code for doing this than the following?

```
for key, value := range listOfThings {
    if(!value.Enabled) {
        continue;
    }

    doTheThing(key, value)
}
```

The large context -- I'm coming from languages where map/reduce/filter/etc are popular patterns for this sort of thing, but [word on the internet](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/1m25a1/map_reduce_and_filter_in_go/) is that those sorts of higher level abstractions aren't really a go-ish thing to do.

Is there something more elegant than guard/`continue` clauses in my range blocks for this sort of code?

Comment: Nope, this is it. If you the use same condition a lot, you can define a function that takes a closure as an argument, which is called for each value satisfying the condition.

Comment: I don't know if this makes sense in your application, but could you maintain a separate list of things for which `value.Enabled` is true and range over that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> [Simple apply/filter/reduce package.](https://github.com/robpike/filter)
>
> I wanted to see how hard it was to implement this sort of thing in Go,
>   with as nice an API as I could manage. It wasn't hard.
>
> Having written it a couple of years ago, I haven't had occasion to use
>   it once. Instead, I just use "for" loops.
>
> You shouldn't use it either.
>
> Rob Pike

---

Follow Rob's advice. Use for loops.

Comment: wonder why call it "apply" instead of "map", map is a better name? dunno

Comment: oh I see, yeah that makes sense I guess

Comment: for loops are a strange thing, where I come from. No matter what programming language I use

Comment: it would have been great if Rob had elaborated his advice with "because..."

Comment: I disagree, for-loops is kind of beginner level, and using collection methods is an advanced level. It's a shame that Go still doesn't have map/filter/reduce/any/take/skip etc. methods out of the box.

Comment: Why is marked as an answer? This is a highly opinionated statement. Clearly, functional approach has its obvious advantages, otherwise it wouldn't be as popular as it is today, and the fact that Golang is missing features that are considered being basic for most languages nowadays doesn't mean that you "shouldn't use" those.

Comment: This is strongly opinionated and rude.  'I just use "for" loops. You shouldn't use it either.' 
As if he is a programming god or something... Maybe he should learn from Rich Hickey and Clj community on what rationale means...

Comment: a modern language, such as go, isn't equipped with an array library supporting `map`, is a bit strange. I wonder if there's a reason for that. Because that means, what do we do with closure anyway?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Although looks similar, apply and map mean different in different contexts. Check out programming languages like clojure or  data frameworks like python pandas etc.

Comment: @windmaomao I guess it wasn't equipped with such a library because of initial lack of support for generics?

Comment: Several of these comments surprise me.  Rob Pike is an authoritative source because he is one of the language's creators.  Try Googling him.  If you check the official tour, you'll find pages like https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/3.  They have a strong opinion about many best practices.  It does not seem like much of a leap to conclude that he never used the library because it did not fit in with those best practices.  Also, if you were searching for a library that is documented by the author as "should not use", would you get offended or look somewhere else?

Answer (score 23):

If you're still interested, the `go-funk` package will enable you to do map/reduce/filter etc.

This library is at the time of answering regularly updated. The previous library mentioned hasn't been updated in 4 years.

[Github - Go Funk](https://github.com/thoas/go-funk)

Comment: Not sure if "regularly updated" is a vote for or against using it?  I'd generally prefer no updates to my core utilities.

Comment: good point @Magnus but version should be locked in your setup to make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: Well they do have tags.  Based on what i'm seeing this is great.  I'm planning to incorporate it in future projects.  Just the ability to do a slice.Contains() is worth it to me.

Answer (score 18):

March 2022 update:
You might be interested with the `lo` package that implements generics, which came out 15 March 2022 in stable go (1.18). Much like Javascript's Lodash, they are good functional/declarative helpers

https://github.com/samber/lo

Here, `str` is automatically inferred to be `string` because of generics, very cool & powerful

```golang
str, ok := lo.Find([]string{"foobar"}, func(i string) bool {
    return i == "b"
})
```

Answer (score 5):

With Go 1.18, type parameters (generics) enable type-safe functional structures, and some libraries like [gostream](https://github.com/mariomac/gostream) are taking advantage of it. For example:

```
results := stream.Generate(rand.Int).
    Map(func(n int) int {
        return n%6 + 1
    }).
    Limit(5).
    ToSlice()

fmt.Printf("results: %v\n", results)
```

Output:

```
results: [3 5 2 1 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the loop as you did and wrap it to a utils function for reuse.

For multi-datatype support, copy-paste will be a choice.
Another choice is writing a generating tool.

And final option if you want to use lib, you can take a look at https://github.com/ledongthuc/goterators that I created to reuse aggregate & transform functions.

[image]

They are required go1.18 to use that support generic + dynamic type you want to use with.

```golang
// Reduce
total := Reduce(list, 0, func(previous int, current int, index int, list []int) int {
    return previous + current
})
```

```golang
mappedItems := Map(testSource, func(item int64) float64 {
  return float64(item)
})
```

```golang
filteredItems, err := Filter(list, func(item string) bool {
  return item.Contains("ValidWord")
})
```