# What is the equivalent function of Array.prototype.map() in Golang?

Tags: javascript, go

I would like do something like this inline function in go, and don't want to write a for loop...

```
const userIds = Users.map(u => u.Id);
```

Comment: That can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468242/idiomatic-replacement-for-map-reduce-filter-etc

Comment: The Go standard library does not have this functionality as of Go 1.18.  Your choices: seek out third party package, write a for loop, wait for Go 1.19.

Comment: Someone made a lodash golang equivalent - https://github.com/samber/lo

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a package named go-funk to manupulate array/slice.
It may look like lodash in some aspects
Your code may look like this:

```
userIds := funk.Map(Users, func(u structTypeOfUser) int {
        return u.Id
}).([]int);
```

It supports many other familiar functions like find, reduce, filter, contains(include)...
Repository of that package:
https://github.com/thoas/go-funk

Comment: Even better - https://github.com/samber/lo

Comment: Wish I'd found samber/lo when I started learning Golang! So many util functions I can delete from my own codebase now xD